# Change the default dot color in flutter_calendar_carousel

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've created a calendar using the flutter_calendar_carousel package. I want to change the default color of the dot, I tried the following code, it works only one time, then the error message raised from the console. Any idea ? Thanks a lot.

[image]

code:

```
EventList<Event> _markedDateMap = new EventList<Event>(events: {
  new DateTime(2022, 7, 24): [
    new Event(
      date: new DateTime(2022, 7, 24),
      title: '',
      dot: Positioned(child: Container(color: Colors.green, height: 4.0, width: 4.0), bottom: 4.0, left: 18.0),
    )
  ]
});
```

Error Message:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Positioned(left: 18.0, bottom: 4.0) wants to apply ParentData of type StackParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type FlexParentData.

Usually, this means that the Positioned widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Positioned widgets are placed directly inside Stack widgets.
The offending Positioned is currently placed inside a Row widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Positioned ← Row ← Padding ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Stack ← Center ← Padding ← ⋯
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5922:11)
#1      RenderObjectElement._updateParentData (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5939:6)
#2      RenderObjectElement.attachRenderObject (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5961:7)
#3      RenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5635:5)
#4      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6283:11)
...     Normal element mounting (13 frames)
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed, the solution from

https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_calendar_carousel/pull/71

```
                   var mark_icon = Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                      height: 4.0,
                      width: 4.0,
                    );

                    var event =  new Event(
                      date: date,
                      title: 'title'
                      icon: mark_icon,
                    );
```